# How to avoid duration('0days') returning "86400s (~1 days)"

Tags: r, lubridate

I am processing a file in which one column has durations encoded as strings, and I need to convert them to minutes. I am using lubridate::duration for this purpose.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
duration('1days 1hours 1 minutes 1seconds')
# [1] "90061s (~1.04 days)"
```

is correct, but

```
duration('0days 1hours 1 minutes 1seconds')
# [1] "90061s (~1.04 days)"
duration('0days')
# [1] "86400s (~1 days)"
duration('0minutes')
# [1] "60s (~1 minutes)"
```

are not...

https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/15/lubridate-1-6-0/ states that

```
# Missing numerals default to 1. 
# Repeated units are summed
period("hour minute minute")
#> [1] "1H 2M 0S"
```

but in this case the numerals are 0, not missing...
I am working around this by erasing any "0units"

```
t <- '0days  1hours  0minutes 3seconds'
duration(str_replace_all(t, '\\b0.*?\\b', ''))
# [1] "3603s (~1 hours)"
```

but there is probably a better way.
I know my replace breaks if I receive a space between the '0' and the unit, but fortunately this does not happen...

Thanks!

Comment: Actually ended up using: `duration(str_trim(str_replace_all(t, '\\b0+ *[a-zA-Z]+?\\b', '') ))` to fix some special cases.